# Fair Value of 2-dice game

Tags: probability

I roll two 4-sided dies, call them D1 and D2. If D2 >= D1 + 2 (for example - D2 has 3 and D1 has 1), I get $1, else I get nothing. If D1 = D2, the game ends, otherwise I take another turn. What is the fair value of the game?

My line of thought is:
EV = 3/16(1) + 4/16(0) + 9/16(EV) => EV = 3/7.

Is that right?

Comment: Looks ok to me.

Comment: Does the game end when you get the dollar or do you continue in that case too?